# Columns as values/Un-pivot table in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following table.

Table_1

| ID | 12/1 | 1/1 | 2/1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| X | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| Y | 4 | 5 | 6 |
| Z | 7 | 8 | 9 |

I want the following table,

| ID | Date | Forecast |
| --- | --- | --- |
| X | 12/1 | 1 |
| X | 1/1 | 2 |
| X | 2/1 | 3 |
| Y | 12/1 | 4 |
| Y | 1/1 | 5 |
| Y | 2/1 | 6 |
| Z | 12/1 | 7 |
| Z | 1/1 | 8 |
| Z | 2/1 | 9 |

Is there anyway I can do this in SQL?

Any help will be appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What you are after is here unpivoting, rather than pivoting.

Comment: Those columns are badly designed: you shouldn't have data in column names. In other words, your final result is how the table should have been in the first place

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UNPIVOT or the VALUES approach would be more performant, BUT based on your column names, I suspect you will have variable/expanding columns over time.

Here is an approach that will dynamically unpivot your data without actually using Dynamic SQL or having to specify the columns (only the ones to exclude)

**Example**

```
Select A.ID
      ,B.* 
 From  YourTable A
 Cross Apply (
                Select Date     = [Key]
                      ,Forecast = Value
                 From OpenJson((Select A.* For JSON Path,Without_Array_Wrapper,INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES  )) 
                 Where [Key] not in ('ID')
             ) B
```

**Results**

```
ID  Date    Forecast
X   12/1    1
X   1/1     2
X   2/1     3
Y   12/1    4
Y   1/1     5
Y   2/1     6
Z   12/1    7
Z   1/1     8
Z   2/1     9
```

Comment: Thanks for this!